# aptitude search ?narrow vs ?and

Tags: aptitude

What is the difference between the `?narrow` and `?and` options of aptitude search? For example, why would `aptitude search "?and(?installed,?origin(backports))"` return results on my system, but `aptitude search "?narrow(?installed,?origin(backports))"` return nothing?

Note that running `apt-cache policy` on the packages returned by the `?and` version shows that versions installed are not from backports, so the `?narrow` result is the correct one. But I've run into similar unintuitive results before which have been solved by using `?narrow` after some googling, but have never understood why.

Comment: I made some extensive clarifications to the old answer, which is retrospect was unclear and even misleading in spots.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Short answer

The first command

```
aptitude search '?and(?installed,?origin(backports))'
```

finds packages that are *installed* and
have a backport *available*,
but the backport is not necessarily installed.
(Maybe the backport is installed, maybe it isn't.)

By contrast, the second command

```
aptitude search '?narrow(?installed,?origin(backports))'
```

finds package that are *installed*,
and the *currently installed version* is from a backport,
i.e. the backports that are actually installed.
This is a more restrictive search,
because the set of *installed* backports is a subset of *available* backports.
You can think of it like this:

- all packages

  - installed packages

    - installed packages with a backport available (first command)

      - installed backports (second command)

On your system, the first command returns results
but the second returns nothing.
This means that you have installed packages with backports available,
but evidently none of those backports are currently installed.

### Long answer

It has to do with aptitude's distinction between
matching the *package* and matching the *package version*.
From the
[documentation](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/aptitude/ch02s04s05.en.html):

> There is a subtle, but important, distinction between matching a pattern
>     against a package, and matching it against all the versions of that
>     package. When a pattern is matched against a package, each of its terms is
>     matched against the package, and so each term will match if *any* version
>     of the package matches. In contrast, when a pattern is matched against each
>     version of a package, it will successfully match if it matches when all its
>     terms are matched against the *same* version of the package.
>
> For example: suppose that version `3.0-1` of the package `aardvark` is
>     installed, but that version `4.0-1` is available. Then the search
>     expression `?version(4\.0-1)?installed` matches aardvark, because
>     `?version(4\.0-1)` matches against version `4.0-1` of aardvark, while
>     `?installed` matches against version `3.0-1`. On the other hand, this
>     expression does not match against all the versions of `aardvark`, because
>     no single version is installed and also has a version number of `4.0-1`.

The [documentation](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/aptitude/ch02s04s05.en.html#searchAnd)
for `?and` reads:

> `?and(pattern1, pattern2), pattern1 pattern2`
>
> Matches packages that match both *pattern1* and *pattern2*.

Note that this matches *packages*, not *single versions*. So this query:

```
aptitude search '?and(?installed, ?origin(backports))'
```

gets a list of all the *package versions* that are installed,
then a list of all the *package versions*
with an origin matching the regular expression `backports`,
and then returns the *packages* that appear in both lists.

On the other hand,
the [documentation](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/aptitude/ch02s04s05.en.html)
for `?narrow` reads:

> `?narrow(filter, pattern), ~S filter pattern`
>
> Select packages for which a single version matches both filter and pattern.

So that's why this query only shows packages
where the *single installed version* has an origin that matches `backports`:

```
aptitude search '?narrow(?installed, ?origin(backports))'
```

There is a related [discussion](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/aptitude/ch02s04s05.en.html#searchAnyVersion)
for the `?any-version` function:

> `?any-version(pattern)`
>
> Matches a package if any one of its versions matches the enclosed pattern.
>
> Note: This term is closely related to `?narrow`. In fact,
>     `?any-version(pattern1 pattern2)` is exactly the same as
>     `?narrow(pattern1, pattern2)`.
>
> Note: To be precise, as with any other pattern, it is not packages but
>     versions of the packages which are matched. For `aptitude search` and other
>     uses it does not make much difference, but `aptitude versions` will only
>     show the versions that match, not all versions of the package for which any
>     version matches.

By running `aptitude versions` instead of `aptitude search`,
we find that these queries all give the same result:

```
aptitude versions '?and(?installed, ?origin(backports))'
aptitude versions '?installed?origin(backports)'
aptitude versions '?narrow(?installed, ?origin(backports))'
```

Whew!
If you find the query language for `aptitude` confusing (as I do),
you may prefer to use a different approach,
such as Python's [bindings to `libapt`](https://apt-team.pages.debian.net/python-apt/).
Rather than matching on version strings,
you can check the origin string directly, like this:

```python
import apt

apt_cache = apt.Cache()

for pkg in apt_cache:
    if pkg.is_installed:
        for pkg_origin in pkg.installed.origins:
            if pkg_origin.origin == 'Debian Backports':
                print(pkg.name)
```